# How can I get Android market RSS feed

Tags: android, rss, google-play

Apple provides an RSS feed for their marketplace. Is there something similar for Android?
I mean something similar to http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a thing available for Android Market.

If you really need it, I suppose you could use pages like the following and parse the content:

https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_paid

Far from a brilliant solution, but I think it's probably one of the best available at the moment.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing anyway.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this as well and found this link:  http://androinica.com/2009/07/tips-follow-the-android-market-with-an-rss-reader-for-beginners/.  Apparently you can do this using Androlib and Cyrket.  The link contains details on how to do it.

Comment: Looks like the Link is dead? Got any other source?