# RSS feed for Google Play Store

Tags: android, mobile

Apple appstore provides you with an RSS feed to get the latest apps submitted into the app store into your favorite feed reader. I was wondering if google play store has an RSS feed as well that lets you do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they don't provide any information for consumption/use by 3rd party developers including RSS.

EDIT: some 3rd parties do seem to have a feed available though [Follow the Android Market with an RSS reader (for beginners)](http://androinica.com/2009/07/tips-follow-the-android-market-with-an-rss-reader-for-beginners/)

Edit 2: [More evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998995/how-can-i-get-android-market-rss-feed)

Comment: If I had to take a guess I'd say scrape the HTML from the market site. But I am not affiliated with them in anyway, so truthfully I wouldn't know.