# Equivalent to rss.itunes generator for Google Play

Tags: android, rss, google-play, itunes

I know that it's not a pure programming question,

So I asked it on android.stackexchange.com, but unfortunately no one sees that.

I want to get statistics about apps on Google Play (not my app)

I noticed this API by Apple:

https://rss.itunes.apple.com/

This API gives statistics about apple app store

Is there an alternative RSS/API for Android Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two git repositories that do it for Android:

1. [Ruby Android Market Scraper (Google Play)](https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot)
2. [Node.js Google play scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is such a thing available for Android Market.

1. If you really need it, I suppose you could use pages like the following and parse the content:

https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_paid

2. some 3rd parties do seem to have a feed available though [Follow the Android Market with an RSS reader (for beginners)](http://androinica.com/2009/07/tips-follow-the-android-market-with-an-rss-reader-for-beginners/)
3. 3rd party site http://www.appbrain.com/

Note: This answer copy & paste from this [SO Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703411/rss-feed-for-google-play-store/11703465#11703465) & [SO Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998995/how-can-i-get-android-market-rss-feed/7999564#7999564).