# Google play store app update rss feed

Tags: rss, google-play

I'm looking for an RSS feed that enables me to subscribe to certain app updates for the Google Play Store. For example: I subscribe to the Whatsapp updates and then every time there is an update available, I get notified via RSS. If it doesn't exist yet, can you help me get on track by linking to an API that does this?

Comment: try this https://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/app/feederco-rss-feed-reader/#

Comment: I am looking for an RSS feed, not a feed reader. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998995/how-can-i-get-android-market-rss-feed

Comment: This doesn't enable me to subscribe to update and it doesn't list all apps. (talking about androlibs, other site is dead)

Comment: @redfast00, did you have any luck finding rss feed or some other solution?

Comment: @Dhunju_likes_to_Learn no, didn't find anything, so I wrote something myself: https://github.com/redfast00/update-checker . However, I wrote it a long time ago and don't plan to support it anymore, but the code is open. I don't accept issues, but I do accept PR's.